# Evaluating the execution time of 1d cuFFT

Tags: cuda, cufft

The code snippet

```
   cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

   /* creates 1D FFT plan */
   cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH);
   /* executes FFT processes */
   cufftExecC2C(plan, devPtr, devPtr, CUFFT_FORWARD);

   cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
   cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
```

measures both the time required by the cuFFT to create a plan and the execution time.

How to measure only the execution time without including also the time needed for the creation of the plan?

Comment: put `cudaEventRecord(start, 0)` after `cufftPlan1d()`? Also I think you need `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after `cufftExecC2C()`

Comment: @SagarMasuti Perhaps you should post your comment as an answer. I have anyway downvoted this question since it does not show any effort in the understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The time needed to calculate the execution time without the plan creation time can be measured with the following snippet. Its just the rearranging your lines in the question.

```
cufftResult     cuRet ;

/* creates 1D FFT plan */
cuRet = cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH);
if (CUFFT_SUCCESS != cuRet)
{
    printf ("Failed in plan creation\n") ;
    return ;
}

cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
/* executes FFT processes */
cuRet = cufftExecC2C(plan, devPtr, devPtr, CUFFT_FORWARD);
if (CUFFT_SUCCESS != cuRet)
{
    printf ("Failed in FFT execution\n") ;
    return ;
}
if (cudaThreadSynchronize() != cudaSuccess)
{
    printf("Failed to synchronize\n");
    return;
}

cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
```

Do remember to check the return values of the `cudaEventRecord` and `cudaEventSynchronize` for errors which I have not shown but you can find the proper way to check the errors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).